# How do I toggle a boolean in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, boolean, variable-assignment, xor

In Javascript (and many other languages), we can just do this:

```
arrayOfObjects[i].propertyAlsoArray[j] ^= true;
```

Typescript disallows logical `^`, `&` and `|` operators. This is [a safety feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/587), so I'd have to do it like this:

```
arrayOfObjects[i].propertyAlsoArray[j] = !arrayOfObjects[i].propertyAlsoArray[j];
```

*Is there a shorter way that avoids the repetition?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that in javascript as well:

```
let bool = true;
console.log(bool == true); // true
console.log(bool === true); // true

bool ^= true;
console.log(bool == false); // true
console.log(bool === false); // false
```

As you can see, the value after the "toggle" isn't a `false`, it's a `0`.
That's why the compiler complains about it, because you're changing the type of your variable from `boolean` to `number`.

If you don't mind this change in types then you can do something like:

```
function toggle(arr: { propertyAlsoArray: number[] }[], i: number, j: number) {
    arr[i].propertyAlsoArray[j] ^= 1;
}

let arr: { propertyAlsoArray: (boolean | number)[] }[];
toggle(arr as { propertyAlsoArray: number[] }[], 1, 1);
```

But what you have now with `!=` is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a shorter way.
You could do this

```
const toggle = (array: Array<bool>, index: number): void => {
  array[index] = !array[index];
}
toggle(arrayOfObjects[i].propertyAlsoArray, j);
```

It ll depends on how many times you need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked a long time ago but it may help others, the shorthand to Toggle a value on TypeScript is:

```
let yourVar = false;

  varToggle() {
  this.yourVar = !this.yourVar;    
}
```